# Find the PDF of $\max(R_1,R_2)/\min(R_1,R_2)$ for $(R_1,R_2)$ i.i.d. standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$R_1, R_2$ are two **independent continuous** random variables, they all satisfied in the following normally distributed equation.
$$f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2}$$
The problem is to find $R_3=\frac{max(R_1, R_2)}{min(R_1, R_2)}$.
So here is how I do this:
$$F_3(z)=P\{ \frac{max(R_1, R_2)}{min(R_1, R_2)}≤z \}$$
$$F_3(z)=P\{ \frac{R_1}{R_2}≤z;R_1>R_2 \} + P\{ \frac{R_2}{R_1}≤z;R_1<R_2 \}$$
$$F_3(z)=P\{ R_1≤zR_2; R_1>R_2 \} + P\{ \frac{R_2}{z}≤R_1; R_1<R_2 \}$$
$$f_3(z)=\frac{d}{dz}F_3(z)=P\{R_2\cdot f_{R_1}(zR_2)\} + 
P\{\frac{R_2}{z^2}\cdot f_{R_1}(\frac{R_2}{z})\}$$
And finally, I stuck here, this is the integral formula I derived, but this is probably wrong, please help me.
$$\int_0^\infty x \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2} \cdot
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-z^2x^2}{2} + \frac{x}{z^2} \cdot 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2} \cdot 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2z^2}dx
$$

Comment: As often, the focus on CDFs only makes things more difficult. Instead, note that, if $(X,Y)$ is i.i.d. with common PDF $f$ then $(U,V)=(\max(X,Y),\min(X,Y))$ has joint PDF $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=2f(u)f(v)\mathbf 1_{v<u}$$ hence $(Z,V)=(U/V,V)$ has PDF $$f_{Z,V}(z,v)=|v|f_{U,V}(zv,v)$$ and finally $Z$ has PDF $$f_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{Z,V}(z,v)\,dv$$ Can you perform these steps when $f$ is the standard gaussian PDF?

Comment: For a more elaborate approach, recall that $(R_1,R_2)=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$ where $R>0$ and $\Theta$ are independent and $\Theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$ hence you are after the distribution of $\max(\cos\Theta,\sin\Theta)/\min(\cos\Theta,\sin\Theta)$, which can be computed, decomposing the unit circle into cases.